# Return double type without trialing zero

Tags: java, double, number-formatting

I am trying to return the double/float value but without the trailing zero added to it.

I've used NumberFormat, DecimalFormat but once I cast double or float to the result, it will add trailing zero(which is expected). I was wondering if there is a way to prevent this.

```
        private Double format (double input) {        

        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance(Locale.US);           
        Double result = null; 
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(input); 
        
        if(bd.intValue() > 99){
        //(don't want to add trailing zeros here)
                return (double)bd.intValue();
        }else{
            nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
            nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);
            result = Double.parseDouble(nf.format(bd.doubleValue()));
        }
        return result;
```

P.S. I am not trying to return String value here.

Answer (score 1):

The "trailing zeros" is only about the string representation of a float or double number.

As the trailing zeros do not affect the value of a number, the data stored in the float or double remains the same. For example, "3.4" and "3.4000" are the same number, it's only two different representations of this number, like "3.4 e+00" is still another way to display that very same number.

Comment: And using String.Format() you can easily change how that number is printed.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use **`stripTrailingZeros`** which inbuilt method in Java that returns a `BigDecimal` after remove trailing zero.

```
Double.valueOf(bd.stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you assign an `int` value to a `double` variable, it will always be represented with a trailing zero by default. You have two choices:

1. Format it into a string in whichever you want.
2. Convert it into a `BigDecimal` and then use [`BigDecimal#stripTrailingZeros`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros()) to get a `BigDecimal` without the trailing zero.

   ```
   import java.math.BigDecimal;

   public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           double x = 5;
           System.out.println(x);

           BigDecimal y = BigDecimal.valueOf(x).stripTrailingZeros();
           System.out.println(y);
       }
   }
   ```

**Output:**

```
5.0
5
```